# Rmarkdown graficos

Tags: r-markdown

Tengo un inconveniente respeto a generar graficas para un Rmarkdown , activo las paqueterias necesarias ( Distribuciones o modelos probabilisticos )las corro por consola o chunk y perfectamente puedo visualizarlas, pero a la hora de hacer Knit y montarlas al Rmarkdown, me sale este error : erro en la funcion, dice que no la encuentra "calls Anonimus" Whitvisible -> eval_with_user handlers ejecucion interrumpida, agradeceria el aporte, pues me sirve para la academia, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido CRISTIAN EDUARDO QUIMBAYO CARD a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si trabajas en R, entiendo que conoces el concepto de "reproducibilidad", para ayudarte necesitamos "reproducir" el error, y para eso necesitaríamos que agregues a tu pregunta un [mcve].  ¿Hay de casualidad en tu código algún `stop()`?